# Maven remove project from cache?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have build a *Maven* project before, and after that I've started a normal Java project under the same folder name (after removing the *Maven* project).

*Intellij* somehow still thinks of it as a *Maven* project and I'm getting all sorts of build errors because of it. For instance, when running a simple `main` method, I get an error that some class that previously existed cannot be found.

Is there some cache folder storing *Maven* project data, and can I remove this?

This is the complete project structure (it is a school project and I'm experimenting, that's why I'm combining JS and Java files in the same project).

**Please note, QuicksortTest.java never existed in the current project, it did in the previous and deleted *Maven* project.**

[image]

Comment: type `mvn clean` in the project directory (or use idea to run that)

Comment: Try to disable the `maven nature` by right-clicking `Project` then `Maven` and `Disable Maven Nature`

Comment: Did you remove the old project with `.idea` directory when IntelliJ IDEA was not running? Otherwise it will still have the old project definitions and settings there.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Intellij was running, but I've closed that project beforehand. Intellij doesn't track every known project that isn't opened while running all the time does it?

Comment: Closing project should be enough. To ensure search the project directory for the problematic class name reference.